# Kotlin: Convert String[] to Any to ArrayList<String>

Tags: arrays, kotlin, arraylist

Need to convert `String[]` and pass it on a parameter that has `Any` data type, then from Any need to convert it to `ArrayList<String>`. Tried this but not working as it returns memory address.

```
arrayOf(anyObject).map { it.toString() }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast anyObject to Array, not create a new Array with anyObject as Element:

```
val str = arrayOf("a", "b", "c")
val anyObject: Any = str
val result = (anyObject as Array<*>).map { it.toString() }

println(result)   // [a, b, c]
```

Comment: `Array<*>` is the key, thank you

Comment: Just realised that only the first version is correct. The other two do __not__ return List<String>, but List<Any?>, so I am removing them, as they do not correspond to the question asked.